# How do I combine and average the values in a dataframe matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a dataframe that contains two matrices that I attached in an excel file. These matrices have the same y values (0,25,50...150) and x values (0,50,100...175).

I would like to do two things and am struggling:

1. Combine the duplicate columns and show the average. I.e., there are two columns for 0, two for 50, two for 100, etc.
2. Combine the identical rows. I.e., there are two rows with the value of 0, 25, etc., and I would like to show the average.

This should result in one smaller matrix.
Here is an excerpt of the data (the actual matrix is larger).

**150  150.1   125  125.1   100  100.1**
**0**    6608   6650  4838   3850  5015
**25**   2191   7053  3799   3712  7656
**50**   8425   6532  4258   4318  7883
**75**   8126   6517  4014   4126  7960
**0**    4945   6791  3887   3827  7759
**25**   6339   6522  4671   4672  7873
**50**   6594   6899  5161   4963  7420
**75**   6362   7013  5038   4842  7037

I have tried variations of .groupby and .mean but I can't figure out how to do this other than by manually taking the mean of each two columns, which is incredibly timeconsuming and bloats the dataframe. Plus I have no idea how to even start with the rows...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df.mean(axis=0, level=0)`.

Comment: Have you got access to the two matrices independently? That would make the task a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you both! I used the first comment to combine rows and the second to get rid of the columns!